# How could I find an element with similar ID in JS?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In my page I have labels that look like this:

```
ContentPlaceHolder1_gvGroups_lblName_0
```

with corrosponding:

```
ContentPlaceHolder1_gvGroups_lblHidden_0
```

I can assert that any *lblName has a corrosponding *lblHidden.

Now, I have some js:

```
//use to make any label with 'edit' class editable
function makeLabelsEditable() {

    $(".edit").focusout(function () {
        setLabel(this);
    });

    $(".edit").click(function () {
        editLabel(this);
    });
}

//used to edit labels
function editLabel(source) {
    source.innerHTML = '<input type="text" maxlength="40" value="' + source.innerHTML + '"/>';
    $(source).unbind('click');
    source.children[0].focus()
}

//used to edit labels
function setLabel(source) {

    if (source.children[0].value != '') {
        $(source).click(function () {
            editLabel(this);
        });
        source.innerHTML = source.children[0].value;
    }

}
```

I can assert that anything marked with class edit will be valid.

I need to modify this code like so:
//used to edit labels

```
function setLabel(source) {

    if (source.children[0].value != '') {
        $(source).click(function () {
            editLabel(this);
        });
        source.innerHTML = source.children[0].value;
        var hidden = someHowGetHiddenFromSource(source);
        hidden.innerHTML = source.children[0].value;
    }

}
```

I'm sure this is possible, I just do not know how.

Essentially, it would be something like:

```
getElementByID(replace(source.id,'lblName','lblHidden'));
```

I just do not know what JS / JQ functions can do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Essentially, it would be something like:
>   `getElementByID(replace(source.id,'lblName','lblHidden'));`

That's almost exactly it. It's:

```
var hidden = document.getElementById(source.id.replace('lblName', 'lblHidden'));
```

`hidden` will be the DOM element.

Or using jQuery:

```
var hidden = $("#" + source.id.replace('lblName', 'lblHidden'));
```

`hidden` will be a jQuery instance wrapping the element.

The `id` property of DOM elements is a string. JavaScript strings have a `replace` function which accepts, in the simple case, the string to replace and the replacement string. (There's more to it than that, but that's all you need in this case.)